# How to make Animation with setInterval()?

Tags: javascript

I have a slider of 10 pictures. Switching pictures without animation.  I need to implement a smooth transition of pictures with animation.    Without `CSS-transition`, with `setInterval()` Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you use CSS's `transition`? Regardless, you're able to use `setAnimationFrame`, which is better than `setInterval` for animations.

Comment: I study javascript, I wanted to try.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to animate the opacity of a html element:

```js
var o = 1.0; // start opacity
var d = false; // direction. false = decrease, true = increase
var s = 0.02; // step
function anim()
{
    if (d == false)
    {
        o -= s;
        if (o < 0.0)
        {
            o = 0.0;
            d = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        o += s;
        if  (o > 1.0)
        {
            o = 1.0;
            d = false;
        }
    }
    
    document.getElementById("pic").style.opacity = o;
}

setInterval(anim, 1000/60); // 60 FPS.
```

```html
<div id="pic" style="background:red;width:100px;height:100px;">Picture</div>
```

It's slow, long code and you only have a linear effect (compared to CSS). It would also be possible to implement a bezier curve effect but the code would get longer and more complex.

Comment: Regarding the `don't know if setInterval supports floats`. In JavaScript `Number` is a double-precision 64-bit floating point number and `Math.round` still returns floating-point number. So you don't need the `Math.round`, except you really want to do the rounding. For integer numbers, you need to use `BigInt`, but `BigInt` is really new and not support in every browser yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like jQuery? it comes with functions like `.animate()` which let's you do the animation you want. There are other javascript libraries out there that add functionality like that.
Have a look at them here: [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [Velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/), [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap)